# Drag & Drop with GLFW-b

Tags: user-interface, haskell, drag-and-drop, glfw

How do I respond to drag-and-drop events with the [GLFW-b](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b) package? There is a `glfwSetDropCallback` function listed on the GLFW website, but it seems to have been excluded from the Haskell bindings.

GLFW-b relies on the low-level [bindings-GLFW](https://github.com/bsl/bindings-GLFW/blob/master/Bindings/GLFW.hsc) package, which *does* include the aforementioned function (defined in *input.c*) and the [release note](http://www.glfw.org/Version-3.1-released.html) for version 3.1 even lists drag-and-drop among the new features.

Is this just an accidental omission or are there issues with cross-platform drag-and-drop that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Support for the drop callback exists in the C-side of the `GLFW-b` package, but not in the FFI/Haskell side of both `bindings-GLFW` and `GLFW-b`.</s>

I created branches (& pull requests) for both packages, see:

https://github.com/lamdu/bindings-GLFW

https://github.com/lamdu/GLFW-b

Support for drag&drop is now inside the GLFW-b Haskell packages.

Comment: Thank you! The GLFW repo is on my watchlist so I was notified about it earlier today.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake My branches are no longer needed (deleted), the packages added internal support.